# How to pass empty value to a query param in swagger?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to access an url similar to http://example.com/service1?q1=a&q2=b. However q1 will not have any values associated with it sometimes but is required to access the service (http://example.com/service1?q1=&q2=b). How do I achieve this through swagger ui JSON. I've tried using allowEmptyValue option but it doesn't seem to work.

Please find below the sample JSON I tried using allowEmptyValue option,

```
{
    "path": "/service1.do",
    "operations": [{
        "method": "GET",
        "type": "void",
        "parameters": [{
                "name": "q1",
                "in" : "query",
                "required": false,
                "type": "string",
                "paramType": "query",
                "allowEmptyValue": true
            },{
                "name": "q2",
                "in" : "query",
                "required": true,
                "type": "string",
                "paramType": "query",
            }


        ],
        "responseMessages": [{
            "code": 200,
            "responseModel": "/successResponseModel"
        }
}
```

When an empty value is passed to q1, swagger frames the URL as http://example.com/service1?q2=b. Is there anyway to include q1 with empty values to be included in the URL (http://example.com/service1?q1=&q2=b) ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne we treat is a special case, wherein an empty value for q1 does a specific operation

Comment: so http://example.com/service1?q1=&q2=b works in direct-call without swagger-ui right?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne yep..

Comment: I think the best way you can find out what went wrong here is capturing and inspecting the HTTP packet of your swagger request with a packet capturing  tool like wire-shark. It's better if you can share a screen shot. :)

Comment: @SupunWijerathne I think you misunderstood me.. I've updated the question.. please refer it..

Comment: Are you able to set default to an empty string? I don't have it setup right now to try it conclusively.

Comment: @Anand actually you have added what I wanted. :D

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your problem is a known issue of swagger-ui that hasn't fixed yet. [see](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1934).

As a workaround you may do one of the followings.

**Option 1: Specify a default value.**

This option have nothing to do with swagger-ui. In your ws-implementation, You have to add a default value(in your case "") to use when 'q1' is not added. Any REST framework has this option.

As the ws-implementation perspectives, this **should** be there in your ws, **unless you have another service to be triggered when 'q1' is not added. (which might not be a good design in most cases)** And you can use this as a forever solution, not temporary.

**Option 2: using enums (not a consistent solution)**

As Explained in [this](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/swagger-swaggersocket/156mevzq8t/is-there-a-way-to-specify-query-parameter-without-value). You can specify your query parameter 'q1' as follows for your swagger definition.

```
{
                 "in": "query",
                 "name": "q1",
                 "type": "boolean",
                 "required": false,
                 "enum" : [true],
                 "allowEmptyValue" : true
}
```

> (1) "required" must be false.
>
> (2) "allowEmptyValue" must be true.
>
> (3) "enum" must have exactly one non-empty value.
>
> (4) "type" must be "boolean". (or "string" with a special enum, say "INCLUDE")

Comment: i cannot possibly use your option 1 since I have to change hundreds of web services and your option 2 prevents the user from giving his input since q1 can take values only a set of values mentioned in the enum.

Comment: @Anand if option1 is available to do, (if doesn't affect to specifications of your endpoints), it is the best way to go, not only to solve your swagger problem, but the overall implementation goals. Though you have to change hundreds of them, It will take only few clicks, if you use your IDE efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this by setting:

```
"required": true,
"allowEmptyValue": true
```

In the Swagger-UI a checkbox will then be displayed where you can send the empty value. That worked for me. If that was checked and an empty query parameter was passed, the URL would look something like this: https://example.com?